# image slider using programming language called Processing

Tags: processing

I don`t know how to create an image slideshow with processing. Can someone please create a slideshow for me to use as a sample? And can you briefly explain the codes using"statements"?

Comment: This isn't really how StackOverflow works. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than by pointing you to google. What have you tried?

Comment: @Safwan Chaudhry How would you build a slideshow ? How do you [load an image](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html) ? How about two ? How do you [display an image](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) ? How do you [know when a key is released](https://processing.org/reference/keyReleased_.html) ? Can you change what image gets displayed when that happens ? What about managing a [list/array](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html) of images ? Perhaps filtering by image extensions, list files in a directory(**File > Examples > Topics > File IO > Directory List**) ?...

Comment: ...The idea is try using the [reference](https://processing.org/reference/) and examples your already have with Processing. It would help a lot if you familiarise yourself with the basics of programming(variables, conditions, for loops, arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Since, you didn't try anything and you don't provide any code, consider the below as a beginning:

- Slideshow is a list/array of images appearing at the exact position in a
  specific order. At any given time, only one image must be visible.
- Also, consider PIMAGE data type and image() method.

You can find more in [Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/).
And just be creative. There is not any rule to make a slideshow. You can do it in many different ways.